# Dynamic legendlabel for a rule-based style

Tags: qgis, style, rule-based, labeling

I have a rule-based style that is linked to a print-composer.  In that composer I activated the atlas-function with a filter.

Because of that filter the outcome of the rule-based style varies.

[image]

Is there a way to make the labels in the legend also dynamic, so the legend shows the exact results without putting them in manually?

I'm using QGIS 2.18.18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a work-around that you could do.

If you remove all of the labels from the legend (so you only have the boxes), then put a label (print composer label) in the print composer where you can insert in functions.

You could have one label per legend item, or all in the same one if your spacing lines up correctly.

You could also set up a feature request for this, as I can see use cases.

Comment: that's the way I do now.  I just hoped someone had the sollution.  I will make a feature request.